# font preview on OpenOffice?

Tags: fonts, openoffice

Is there a way to show a font preview in OpenOffice that is more comprehensive than just showing the font name in the font in question? I'd like to see all the uppercase & lowercase letters and a "quick brown fox" sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method I see is to type "The quick ... lazy dog" out as a sample. Select it, then visit:

> Format > Character.

The selected text will be previewed rather than the font name.

[image: font preview]

Problems with this method: it will display the first 25 characters or so then truncate at the nearest space. This can be avoided by not using spaces, and fit 52ish characters in the window, but then you might lose the effect of the breaks.

There may be better methods out there but this one is within the program.

Alternatively, you could cycle through the font toolbar with the text selected. But that might involve too much clicking.

Beyond that you can use a Windows tool called fontview.exe (located in `%windir%\System32\`) (Other OSs might have similar programs).

I'm running OpenOffice 3.1.0 Full Install, no modifications.

Comment: I did select text + then Format -> Character, as you suggested, and I don't get the preview. Is there a plugin or a preference setting that enables this?

Comment: huh, weird, it works ok on my Windows PC at work, it didn't on my Mac at home... will try again. oh well.